# Object Initializer where property isn't assigned

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I had a type-o in my windows-8 app store code.  I got a strange result, so I went back to look and realized I missed a value, but it still compiled and ran without errors.  Thinking this was strange, I went and tried it in a windows 8 console application, and in that context it is a compile error!  What gives?

App store version:

```
var image = new TextBlock()
            {
                Text = "A",    //Text is "A"
                FontSize =     //FontSize is set to 100
                Height = 100,  //Height is NaN
                Width = 100,   //Width is 100
                Foreground= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
            };
```

Console version:

```
public class test
{
    public int test1 { get; set; }
    public int test2 { get; set; }
    public int test3 { get; set; }
    public int test4 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test testObject = new test()
                          {
                              test1 = 5,
                              test2 =
                              test3 = 6, //<-The name 'test3' does not exist in the current context                         
                              test4 = 7
                          };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the class in which your first block of code was located had a property called `Height`, and so the compiler was interpreting it as:

```
var image = new TextBlock()
            {
              Text = "A",
              FontSize = this.Height = 100,
              Width = 100,
              Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
            };
```

That would also explain why your `image.Height` property was `NaN` -- your initializer never tried to set it.

On the other hand, the `Program` class where your second block of code is located doesn't have any members named `test3`, and so the compiler barfed on it.

The problem is clearer if you rewrite your initializer code as old-school property assignments:

```
test testObject = new test();
testObject.test1 = 5;
testObject.test2 = test3 = 6; // What is test3?
testObject.test4 = 7;
```

Comment: Take a closer look. The second object does have a `test3` member.

Comment: The `test` class he's creating an instance of has a property called `test3`, yes, but the surrounding class (`Program`) doesn't -- he's trying to assign a value called `test3` to the property `testObject.test2`, and the compiler can't find a variable or property by that name in the current context, so it doesn't like it.

Comment: Just to further clarify - the second code block should compile if we add a member to the `Program` class - `static int test3;`

Comment: Heh, right you are.  It didn't even occur to me that it wasn't a property of the same object.  Still... that seems like a poor choice to allow an assignment of a variable which is not part of the object inside of the object initializer.

Comment: Well, that would make initializers pretty darn limited.  You'd only be able to assign literals, and objects you can initialize using literals.

Comment: @JeremyTodd How so?  I've never tried to assign a value to a member of the _containing_ object when initializing a new object.

Comment: @mydogisbox Oh, I see what you're saying.  I dunno, I'd rather have enough rope to hang myself instead of not enough rope to do what I want. :)

Comment: @JeremyTodd It just seems to entirely defeat the purpose of having an initializer.  Pretty much the only reason I can see to use an initializer is for clarity of intent and ... well ... this entirely defeats that.